# regular expression to replace links

Tags: javascript, regex, angularjs

I have following code to create html links in a plain text. This works fine but the link should not contain .png or .jpg

Any suggestions in adapting the regexp?

```
var urlPattern = /(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/gi;

return function(text, target) {

    var replace = text.replace(urlPattern, '<a target="' + target + '" href="$&">$&</a>');

    return replace
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add anchors and a look-ahead with alternatives to add the restriction:

```js
var urlPattern = /^(?!.*(?:png|jpg)$)(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?$/gi;

  function repl (text, target) {
     var replace = text.replace(urlPattern, '<a target="' + target + '" href="$&">$&</a>');
     return replace;
  };

alert(repl("http://some.site.com/new/1.gif", "_blank"));
alert(repl("http://some.site.com/new/1.png", "_blank"));
```

The crucial part here is `^(?!.*(?:png|jpg)$)`: it makes the check start at the beginning of a string, and makes sure there is no `png` nor `jpg` at the end.

If you pass longer strings with URLs inside, you can use [the following regex](http://jsfiddle.net/d4b9u2u9/1/) that assumes you have no spaces in your URLs:

```
var urlPattern = /(?!\S*(?:png|jpg)(?:$|\s))(http|ftp|https):\/\/[\w-]+(\.[\w-]+)+([\w.,@?^=%&amp;:\/~+#-]*[\w@?^=%&amp;\/~+#-])?/gi;
```